# c++: RedrawWindow() Flickering

Tags: c++, mfc

As a developer who is building a Custome Splitter Wnd using custom class inherited from CWnd.
Initially, the screen has one window (custom class - CTile) which has two buttons(vertical - split, horizontal - split).
When user clicks one of two buttons, the red split bar is appeared and two child window (CTile) is appeared.
As you know, while user drag the red split bar, the child window must be modified.
What I say here is that at this moment, the flickering is appeared.
The parent wnd has only three elements(two child windows and one split bar), so I think that it never require content of drawing. I mean WM_PAINT message handler.
Here's my code.

```
this->cDiv = new CDivider(this->wth_tile / 2, 1);
this->cDiv->CreateDivider(this, this->hgt_tile);

//cDiv is split bar I used custom class which is inherited from CWnd.
//CreateDivider() is also my self-defined method.

this->first_child = new CTile();

// As I mentioned above, CTile is divided child window which is also inherited from CWnd.

POINT pt;
pt.x = 0;
pt.y = 0;
this->first_child->CreateTile(this, this->cDiv->sd_pos, this->hgt_tile, pt);

this->second_child = new CTile();


pt.x = this->cDiv->sd_pos + 5;
pt.y = 0;

this->second_child->CreateTile(this, this->cDiv->sd_pos, this->hgt_tile, pt);

This is make movable split bar wnd creation code.

And next is about modified child window size while drag the split bar.

void CDivider::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

POINT pt;
HDC hdc;
RECT rect;

this->parentWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);

//convert the mouse coordinates relative to the top-left of
//the window
ClientToScreen(&point);
pt = point;
pt.x -= rect.left;
pt.y -= rect.top;

if (this->sd_mode == 1)
{
    ::SetCursor(AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_SIZEWE));
    if (GetCapture() == this && this->dragged)
    {
        this->sd_pos = pt.x;
        if (pt.x != oldPos.x && nFlags & MK_LBUTTON)
        {
            this->length = this->parentWnd->hgt_tile;
            this->MoveWindow(this->sd_pos, 0, 4, this->length);
            this->parentWnd->ResizeParent();
            this->parentWnd->Invalidate();
            this->parentWnd->UpdateWindow();
            TRACE("Resize Parent\n");
            /*this->parentWnd->first_child->Invalidate();
            this->parentWnd->second_child->Invalidate();*/
        }
    }

}
else if (this->sd_mode == 2)
{
    ::SetCursor(AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_SIZENS));

    if (GetCapture() == this && this->dragged)
    {
        this->sd_pos = pt.y;
        if (pt.y != oldPos.y && nFlags & MK_LBUTTON)
        {
            this->Invalidate();
            this->length = this->parentWnd->wth_tile;
            this->MoveWindow(0, this->sd_pos, this->length, 4);

            this->parentWnd->ResizeParent();
            this->parentWnd->Invalidate();
            this->parentWnd->UpdateWindow();
            TRACE("Resize Parent\n");
            /*this->parentWnd->first_child->Invalidate();
            this->parentWnd->second_child->Invalidate();*/
        }
    }
}

CWnd::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
```

}

Here, parentWnd is split bar's parent window - just parent initial window.
first_child and second_child is child divided windows.
sd_mode means that split method - vertical & horizontal.

Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: Do your create parent window with `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` windows style?

Comment: WS_CLIPCHILDREN? I have never used WS_CLIPCHILDREN. only WS_VISIBLE and WS_CHILD were used to create window. @VTT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flickering happens because painting is in most normal windows a two phase operation. 1. The background is erased, 2. The window is repainted.

So the problem is the child window that needs redrawing. There are a lot of articles about non flickering painting.

Also you can optimize the redrawing in just invalidating just the parts of windows that are affected. You force a redraw of the complete windows. That isn't ideal. In such a case a large portion of the window might flicker.

BTW: RedrawWindow with the specific flags are better than calling Invalidate/Update sequences and may be a tick faster.

Also it may be better to use a method to draw Bars with an XOR-Paining during dragging. And update the window size when the LButtonUp-Event happens. The way CSplitterWnd is doing it... you have the source. Look into it.

Comment: I'll try to follow your idea about child window repainting.
And about the specific parts of window, I think that it's also good.
When you said " Also it maybe be better to use a method to draw Bars with an XOR-Painting during dragging.", can you provide some example preciously about it?

Comment: You have the source code of the MFC CSpiltterWnd. Just look into it. You find all you need.

Comment: Ok, And one more thing to ask.
When you said "And update the window size when the LButtonUp-Event happens", but the app requires ,while drag the split bar, that shows the window size and other info.
What is your idea about this?

Comment: Show the window size in any window you want, but do the resize later...